# How to use cufon fonts on svg file?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, cufon, snap.svg

Is that possible to use cufon fonts on an svg file? I know using Raphael you can use the print method to use cufon fonts, like this:

```
Paper.print(x, y, string, font, [size], [origin], [letter_spacing])
```

Deos anybody have any other way of using the cufon fonts on an svg file? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Update: I was thinking about this:

```
  var s= Snap("#svg1");

  var text1 = s.text(10,150,"Snap.svg is great!").attr(

  {fill:"black", id : "text1", fontSize:"25px"});

  //Snap.registerFont();

   Cufon.registerFont();

    //Cufon.replace('h1'); // Works without a selector engine

    Cufon.replace('#text1'); 

    console.log(s.toString());
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work the same way as an html would?

http://jsfiddle.net/fzhv0swk/

Comment: What's wrong with Raphael's print method?

Comment: I prefer not to use any libraries, just js and svg. something like: <script>
Cufon.replace('#text1'); 
  </script> or use snap svg, if I have to.

Comment: Raphael is a small library. It's well tested, fully featured, and tackles a lot of problems you haven't even considered. Your code, no matter how well-written, will not be. This is not a wheel I would bother reinventing.

Comment: Thank you @JimmyBreck-McKye, the problem is, I am using snap svg and as you know these 2 are having some commons and therefore they may conflict sometimes. What about adding the print method to snap svg?